# Receive the JSON as an input to the Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I am creating a Controller that should accept the JSON as the input parameter. The JSON is just simple like shown below

```
{ 
 "Barcode" : "M28"
}
```

I have created a Model Class for the above JSON like

```
 public class CodeDTO
 {
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Now, I need to receive this CodeDTO as the input parameter and parse it to find the BarCode

```
 public class SetNameController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(CodeDTO bCode)
    {
      var returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CodeDTO.RootObject>(bCode);
        string Bar_Code = returnObj.Barcode.ToString();

        if (Bar_Code == "" || Bar_Code == null)
        {
            ............
```

But it throws the below error like

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string,
>   params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments

How do I deserialize the JSON and get the elements

Comment: Web API does that for you.  `Get(CodeDTO bCode)` should be `Get(CodeDTO.RootObject bCode)` and get rid of your manual deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do the deserialization yourself, change it as follows:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromBody] CodeDTO.RootObject bCode)
 {
     string Bar_Code = bCode.Barcode.ToString(); 
 }
```

When your are posting you data, specify the content type in your header request:

```
contentType:"application/json"
```